How do i get the id of a row in sql using html, javascript and flask
I have a table called Gerechten with the columns: id, gerecht, beschrijving, categorie, prijs, url and sterren. In this table i have a lot of rows, so i used a jinja loop in the html script to loop through every row and display them, every div is its own meal, so i have a purchase button at the bottom of every div. I was wondering how i could get the id of the meal that was purchased and use it in a javascript script. so that i can add it to the cart.
this is my table in flask:
class Gerechten(db.Model):
  __bind_key__ = 'gerechten'
  __tablename__ = 'gerechten'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  gerecht = db.Column(db.String(80), index=True, unique=True)
  beschrijving = db.Column(db.String(80), index=True)
  categorie = db.Column(db.String(80), index=True)
  prijs = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
  sterren = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
  url = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True)
  db.create_all()

This is my jinja script:
    {% for gerecht in gerechten %}
    
    <div class="Gerechtdiv">
      <img src={{gerecht.url}} class="gerechtimg">
      <h3 class="GerechtTitel">{{gerecht.gerecht}}</h3>
      <p class ="GerechtBeschrijving">{{gerecht.beschrijving}}</p>
      <div class ="BottomGerechtDiv">
        <p style="font-size: 17px;"><b>€{{gerecht.prijs}}</b></p>
        <p>{{gerecht.sterren}}&#9733</p>
      </div>
      <button class="button" onclick=""><span>Voeg toe aan winkelwagen</span></button>
      
    </div>
    
    {% endfor %}

I havent tried anything yet, cause i just cant figure it out

I encountered a similar error when trying to implement like functionality in my social media app
The best way to go about this is to add a data-id attribute and pass in the id to the function using the jinja templating:
  {% for gerecht in gerechten %}
    
    <div class="Gerechtdiv">
      <img src={{gerecht.url}} class="gerechtimg">
      <h3 class="GerechtTitel">{{gerecht.gerecht}}</h3>
      <p class ="GerechtBeschrijving">{{gerecht.beschrijving}}</p>
      <div class ="BottomGerechtDiv">
        <p style="font-size: 17px;"><b>€{{gerecht.prijs}}</b></p>
        <p>{{gerecht.sterren}}&#9733</p>
      </div>
      <button class="button" data-id="{{gerecht.id}}"onclick="FunctionName(event)"><span>Voeg toe aan winkelwagen</span></button>
      
    </div>
    
    {% endfor %}

and then in your script:
function FunctionName(event){
let gerechtId = event.target.dataset.id
}

Make sure just to change the function name the event parameter is required.
